# XPS Printing of Visuals from different thread than the UI thread - is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, xps

Why am I getting this strange exception when I'm trying to write to an XPS document?

```
XpsPackagingException: 
Package already has a root DocumentSequence or FixedDocument.
```

My goal is to print a WPF Visual into an XPS file, but because the visual tree is so big, the printing process could be very slow, so I want to find out how can I print XPS files on a background thread, so my users won't get annoyed because of a frozen application.

Here is my code:

```
Dispatcher otherThreadDispatcher;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
       otherThreadDispatcher =  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
       printIt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(printIt_Click);
       System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}

void printIt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    otherThreadDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
       using (XpsDocument myDoc = new XpsDocument("foo.xps", FileAccess.ReadWrite))
       {
           XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(myDoc);
           var collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();
           collator.BeginBatchWrite();
           collator.Write(someImageToPrint);
           collator.EndBatchWrite();
       }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print a screenshot of the application or part of the application? In this case if you'd do the printing in the background, the user interface could change while printing. That's a problem. I wonder if you can present a throbber to the user so they wouldn't experience a simple "freeze" of the app. In this case your throbbe ritself may get into the XPS though.

Comment: What type is someimagetoprint? Do you get the error also for a blank xps doc?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use asynchronous pattern like *async* and *await* or Tasks? That way you don't have to bother about threading much.

Comment: I think he knows that. That's a tool to make it happen but there are other problems.